# Multiple CSS grids with shared auto-sized column widths

Tags: css, css-grid

I have multiple `div`s on a page each configured for `display: grid` and `grid-template-columns: auto auto auto`. I would like each grid to share the same column widths, except using auto-fit behavior rather than hard coding pixel widths or using `1fr 1fr 1fr`.

In other words I would like to achieve this:

[Grids with shared column layout but placed/styled independently](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k721N.png)

where each column grows to he maximum content width measured across both grids (note the green lines are just to illustrate shared width layouts), instead of this:

[Auto-fitted columns are totally independent between the two grids](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5cgEM.png)

where each respective grid's column widths are based only on their own child cells.

What I'm looking for is the equivalent of `SharedSizeGroup` in WPF `Grid`, for those who are familiar, or a workaround. Basically I would like both grids to be treated as one for purposes of auto-fitted columns but still be separate `div`s that can be placed and styled independently.

A CSS-only solution would be ideal, though I'm fairly sure none exists. I have no problem using Javascript, but even a Javascript solution eludes me short of abandoning `grid` completely and reinventing it.

Either way I need something reasonably scalable (i.e. I don't want to have to set any pixel widths by hand and don't want an ad-hoc solution that would only work for specific layout scenarios).

Is this possible?

Comment: Could I inquire as to the stipulation to not use `1fr 1fr 1fr`? It seems like that would be a suitable fit as a solution. Alternatively, you could try `repeat(3, 1fr)`.

Comment: @Wongjn Sure - sorry if it wasn't clear. I don't want the column widths within each grid to all be equal to each other. I want them to grow to fit their respective contents, but logically link two different grids' respective columns so that the computed column layouts of both grids wind up the same. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ensure all the items are in the same grid. Have the content be inside the grid but expanded across all the grid column tracks.

```html
<div style="display: grid; grid-template-columns: repeat(3, auto);">
  <div>Auto</div>
  <div>Auto</div>
  <div>Auto</div>
  <div>AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA</div>
  <div>BB</div>
  <div>CCCCCCCCC</div>
  <div>AAAAA</div>
  <div>BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB</div>
  <div>CCCCCCCCCCCCC</div>
  <div>AAA</div>
  <div>BBBBBBB</div>
  <div>CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC</div>

  <div style="grid-column: 1 / -1; padding: 2em; text-align: center">Other content</div>

  <div>Auto</div>
  <div>Auto</div>
  <div>Auto</div>
  <div>AAAA</div>
  <div>BBBBBBB</div>
  <div>CCCCCCCCC</div>
  <div>AAAAAAAAA</div>
  <div>BB</div>
  <div>CCCCCCCCC</div>
  <div>AAAAAAAAAAAA</div>
  <div>BBBBBBB</div>
  <div>CCCCC</div>
</div>
```

### Edit in response to comment

You would need to "sync" the grid column tracks with JavaScript. Here, I use the first three elements of the first row of the first table to detect the grid column track widths, and then pass these as the `grid-template-columns` value on the second grid.

```js
document.querySelector('.js-grid-to').style.gridTemplateColumns =
  [...document.querySelector('.js-grid-from').children]
    .slice(0, 3)
    .map((element) => `${element.getBoundingClientRect().width}px`)
    .join(' ');
```

```html
<div class="js-grid-from" style="display: grid; grid-template-columns: repeat(3, auto);">
  <div>Auto</div>
  <div>Auto</div>
  <div>Auto</div>
  <div>AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA</div>
  <div>BB</div>
  <div>CCCCCCCCC</div>
  <div>AAAAA</div>
  <div>BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB</div>
  <div>CCCCCCCCCCCCC</div>
  <div>AAA</div>
  <div>BBBBBBB</div>
  <div>CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC</div>
</div>

<div style="padding: 2em; text-align: center">Other content</div>

<div class="js-grid-to" style="display: grid">
  <div>Auto</div>
  <div>Auto</div>
  <div>Auto</div>
  <div>AAAA</div>
  <div>BBBBBBB</div>
  <div>CCCCCCCCC</div>
  <div>AAAAAAAAA</div>
  <div>BB</div>
  <div>CCCCCCCCC</div>
  <div>AAAAAAAAAAAA</div>
  <div>BBBBBBB</div>
  <div>CCCCC</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hah, yes I had a feeling you or someone might suggest this and you beat me to it before I could clarify the question further. I need to be able to place and style the grids independently. So they really need to be distinct `div`s.

Comment: Added an additional solution. Consider adding all of your stipulations to your original question to avoid having this back and forth.

Comment: I certainly tried to but sorry it wasn't obvious. :) The edit though I think gets us close. One drawback is it would have one grid being the controlling one and the other being the dependent one, and another is that it wouldn't automatically respond to content changes, but I'm thinking both can be addressed. This has given me good ideas, thank you.

Comment: Rather than setting the column widths straight, I'm thinking `minmax(measured,auto)` might do the trick as it would then allow the column to grow wider if its content grew. Then we'd just need size monitors - thinking a fake child for each column with infinite rowspan - that would re-trigger the "synchronization" procedure across all linked grids. Any thoughts on that? I really like the direction this is leading though thank you.